# How to AND all booleans in a list using lambdas?

Tags: java

I have a list of objects from which I extract the booleans and want to apply the AND operation on them. Is there a better (or more concise) way to do this?

```
final boolean[] result = {true};
someList.stream().map(o -> o.getBooleanMember()).forEach(b -> result = result && b);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `reduce` :

```
boolean result = someList.stream().map(o -> o.getBooleanMember()).reduce(true,(a,b)->a&&b);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have org.apache.commons in your dependencies you can use the class from the mutable package:

```
org.apache.commons.lang3.mutable.MutableBoolean
```

Then you can modify this value inside your anonymous functions(lambdas) like this:

```
    List<YourClass> someList = new ArrayList<>();
    MutableBoolean result = new MutableBoolean(true);
    someList.stream().map(YourClass::getBooleanMember).forEach(b -> result.setValue(result.getValue() && b));
```

If you don't have this dependency, you can make your own wrapper.